# android.os.BadParcelableException ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: inner class

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have a parent class called `OuterClass`, which contains a `List` of objects of type `InnerClass`, which is a static inner class of `OuterClass`. The static inner class implements `Parcelable`.

I am running into this error:

```
Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException
ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.example.OuterClass.InnerClass 

android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator + 2535 (Parcel.java:2535)
android.os.Parcel.readParcelable + 2461 (Parcel.java:2461)
android.os.Parcel.readValue + 2364 (Parcel.java:2364)
android.os.Parcel.readListInternal + 2778 (Parcel.java:2778)
android.os.Parcel.readArrayList + 2035 (Parcel.java:2035)
android.os.Parcel.readValue + 2385 (Parcel.java:2385)
android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal + 2717 (Parcel.java:2717)
android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel + 269 (BaseBundle.java:269)
android.os.BaseBundle.getLongArray + 1271 (BaseBundle.java:1271)
android.content.Intent.getLongArrayExtra + 6441 (Intent.java:6441)
com.example.MyFragment.onCreate + 169 (MyFragment.java:169)
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate + 2414 (Fragment.java:2414)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1418 (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1418)
androidx .fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState + 1784  (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1784)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1852 (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1852)
androidx. fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange + 3269 (FragmentManagerImpl.java:3269)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate + 3223 (FragmentManagerImpl.java:3223)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate + 190 (FragmentController.java:190)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate + 369 (FragmentActivity.java:369)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate + 85 (AppCompatActivity.java:85)
com.example.MyBaseActivity.onCreate + 50 (MyBaseActivity.java:50)
android.app.Activity.performCreate + 6757 (Activity.java:6757)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate + 1119 (Instrumentation.java:1119)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity + 2704 (ActivityThread.java:2704)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity + 2812 (ActivityThread.java:2812)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1528 (ActivityThread.java:1528)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 102 (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop + 154 (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6317 (ActivityThread.java:6317)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 872 (ZygoteInit.java:872)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 762 (ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

This crash isn't happening for all users. My stack trace is actually very similar to the one in this post: [How to find source of crashes of type java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@####: Unmarshalling unknown type code XXXX at offset YYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159506/how-to-find-source-of-crashes-of-type-java-lang-runtimeexception-parcel-android)

The weird thing is, the unmarshalling part of the code is not even being executed during runtime, yet I still see this error.

```
public class OuterClass  
{
    List<InnerClass> innerClassList;

    ...
    public static class InnerClass implements Parcelable  
    {
        final String name;
        final String value;

        public InnerClass (Parcel in)
        {
            this.name = in.readString();
            this.value = in.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
        {
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeString(value);
        }

        public static Creator<InnerClass> CREATOR = new Creator<InnerClass>()
        {
            @Override
            public InnerClass createFromParcel(Parcel source)
            {
                return new InnerClass(source);
            }

            @Override
            public InnerClass[] newArray(int size)
            {
                return new InnerClass[size];
            }
        }
    }
```

The inner class is passed between activities/fragments like this:

```
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(INNER_CLASS_LIST, innerClassList);

        innerClassList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(INNER_CLASS_LIST);
```

The crash is being triggered on a seemingly unrelated line of code:

```
myIds = intent.getLongArrayExtra(EXTRA_MY_IDS)
// the intent object also contains a list of InnerClass
```

This internally calls `BaseBundle.unparcel()`, which is then causing the BadParcelableException.

I must be missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A little strange, but it seems like the class isn't initialized. Does it work if you manually initialize the class? e.g.
`Class.forName(OuterClass.InnerClass.class.getName(), true, OuterClass.InnerClass.class.getClassLoader())`

Comment: To add, if that is the problem, the above may or may not work depending on how things are initialized. Another way to find out is to manually instantiate a static instance of `OuterClass.InnerClass` in the application's entry point.

Comment: Just curious why it has to be a `static` instance of `OuterClass.InnerClass`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I was able to instantiate the class at the app entry point.

Comment: If you put this `Parcelable` in an `Intent` and pass that `Intent` to another component, when the "extras" of that `Intent` are accessed, the entire `Bundle` of "extras" must be unpacked, even if there is no direct reference to that specific "extra". This is why you are seeing these crashes on seemingly unrelated code lines.

Comment: Try to add this line prior to the line where the crash occurs: `intent.setExtrasClassLoader(OuterClass.class.getClassLoader());`